# Is there a python function for summing voxel values of two 3D images, stored in lists, and store the output in another list

Tags: python

I have 3D images of size (197,233,189) of which each point in this volume contains a greyscale value. I have two different sorts of images, left hippocampus and right hippocampus. To combine them I just need to sum these images elements wise. In total I have 44 images of each hippocampus. The right hippocampus images are thus stored in a 'vector' containing 44 elements of which each element is a (197,233,189) images. it is the same for the left hippocampus images. I always get the error that the list assignment index is out of range.

I already tried the following code

```py
def make_gt(vector_L_hc, vector_R_hc):
    GT_hc_segmentation = []
    for n in range(len(vector_L_hc)): 
        for x in range(vector_L_hc[n].shape[0]): 
            for y in range(vector_L_hc[n].shape[1]): 
                for z in range(vector_L_hc[n].shape[2]): 
                    GT_hc_segmentation[n][x][y][z] = vector_L_hc[n][x][y][z] + vector_R_hc[n][x][y][z]

    return  GT_hc_segmentation
```

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I also tried the following:

```py
def make_gt(vector_L_hc, vector_R_hc):

    GT_hc_segmentation = []
    for i in range(len(vector_L_hc)):
        GT_hc_segmentation[i] = np.add(vector_L_hc[i], vector_R_hc[i])

    return GT_hc_segmentation
```

This also gives the error : 
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

index 0 of the vector_L_hc and vector_R_hc is a certain image, index 1 the x coordinate, index 2 the y coordinate and index 3 the z coordinate.

I want a new vector, GT_hc_segmentation where one image is the sum of two images, one from vector_L_hc and one from vector_R_hc. 
The outcome would be a list or array ? of the same size as vector_L_hc and one from vector_R_hc.

Answer (score 0):

For your first approach it looks like you may be trying to use list indexing for a multidimensional numpy array.  It's hard to tell because you don't show the code where the objects are declared.  For a numpy array you index like `[i,j,k]` rather than `[i][j][k]`

For your second approach:

```
def make_gt(vector_L_hc, vector_R_hc):

    GT_hc_segmentation = []
    for i in range(len(vector_L_hc)):
        GT_hc_segmentation[i] = np.add(vector_L_hc[i], vector_R_hc[i])

    return GT_hc_segmentation
```

you're not initializing GT_hc_segmentation.  It's empty so you can't index into it like you're trying to do here.  You either need to initialize it with a length or you can dynamically add elements to it like this:

```
def make_gt(vector_L_hc, vector_R_hc):

    GT_hc_segmentation = []
    for i in range(len(vector_L_hc)):
        GT_hc_segmentation.append(np.add(vector_L_hc[i], vector_R_hc[i]))

    return GT_hc_segmentation
```